# Django User Model questions

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django so I have some questions that might seem basic to you. I'm looking to create a platform that is open to both individuals and companies and I'm trying to design the user auth for an API that runs on DRF. I need to provide mobile platform access so I'm thinking of using OAuth via *django-oauth-toolkit*. Having difficulty understanding:

1. Should I separate the login flow into a separate app? How do I know when I should spin up a separate app?
2. Do I manage the profiles via the built in admin area? Is this secure for production environments?
3. Should I separate individual profiles and company profiles into separate apps or just models extending the Base User?
4. How do I allow the individual profiles to link their logins to social media accounts with *django-allauth* while storing extra information like birthday/name etc regardless of which mode of login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my point of view.

1. No need to separate the app. You can manage all the profiles from
   Django admin.
2. It is secure for production environments, django not allow to see
   its credentials or password to anyone, its encrypted.
3. You can create UserProfile model and use django user as Foreignkey
   in this. You can able to add extra field like in this way. OR you
   can extends the User model of Django admin.

Its just a suggest, you do whatever you feel reliable or easy way.

Comment: 1. When I mean secure I mean is the admin area easy to hack thereby releasing control of the entire DB? Should I spin it up on a different node?
2. Is it good practice to extend the base user model for different models?